# Steam market API documentation. Get all skin names

Tags: json, api, steam, steam-web-api, marketplace

**I want to get all skin names** for CS:GO. But I can't find API for use market. Early was some information here: http://steamcommunity.com/dev
but now, I can't find it.

Please give me API documentation, for operate with market and skins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API endpoint like this defined. There never was.

There are different solutions:

- Parse the steam market. I would not recommend this because you will get rate limited really fast and you need to parse HTML
- You can use [SteamAPI.io](https://steamapi.io/docs) or [Steamlytics](http://csgo.steamlytics.xyz/api#v1-items) which both provide a proper API endpoint to get all item information (you can get the lists for free, just signup there and do the api call)